# Why does this code add the same entry from my csv file to the 2d array?

Tags: java

I am reading from a csv file called bookings which has 3 rows currently

```
1,000,Test Name,1,First
2,000,Another Name,2,First
3,001,Yet Another,3,Business
```

I have a method which is meant to read through the file and add each element into a 2d array of bookings, however, the method instead adds the same record to all elements in the 2d array

Output:

```
Bookings: [[3, 001, Yet Another, 3, Business], [3, 001, Yet Another, 3, Business], [3, 001, Yet Another, 3, Business]
```

Code:

```
public class Booker {

    int flightsLength;
    int nextFlight;
    // 2D Array representing bookings
    String[][] bookings = new String[1000][5];
    //        Read bookings from csvr
    //file path
    String path ="bookings.csv";
    //current line being read
    String line;



    public void readBookings() {

        try {
            //new buffered reader object named br
            BufferedReader br;
            System.out.println("RUNNING:");
            //initialise the buffered reader with the file as a parameter
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            //     Store length of flights csv
            flightsLength = getFlightsCount();

            //while next line is available, loop
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] values = line.split(",");

                for (int row = 0; row < flightsLength; row++) {
                    for (int cell = 0; cell <= 4; cell++) {
                        bookings[row][cell] = values[cell];


                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Bookings: " + Arrays.deepToString(bookings));
            System.out.println();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if I should explain the code more or if there is any confusion, and thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read each line, parse it, and then proceed to add its values to ALL the rows from 0 to flightsLength, every time.

Instead you need to read each line, parse it, and then add it to the next row in your bookings.

Effectively, get rid of the `for (int row = 0; row < flightsLength; row++) {` (and the matching `}`) that ruin things for you, and maintain your own `row` index, something like:

```
        int row = 0;
        
        //while next line is available, loop
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            
            for (int cell = 0; cell <= 4; cell++) {
                bookings[row][cell] = values[cell];
            }
            row++;
        }
```